# Shopping cart doesn't show the EURO

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, currency

When a customer adds a product and goes to the shopping cart, the cart total does not show euro but instead just some random stuff, does anyone know the solution to fix this?

> [www.fightgloves.nl](http://www.fightgloves.nl)

[image]

Comment: the problem is somewhere in subtotal iso chartset was set.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040294/%C3%A2-%C2%AC-is-coming-instead-of-regular-euro-sign-in-iso-8859-1-in-magento?answertab=active#tab-top check this for more